# Need to try out bigquery and google cloud sql free package, am asked to enable billing before creating an instance

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

Members, I have been trying to learn how to use google bigquery and the cloud sql though I have had a challenge with enabling billing issues, this is all because I needed is to have a free access package.
Question:
Is there a free package to enable me practice google cloud sql and bigquey, if yes please  get me the link.
Besides any one experiencing the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

This topic is not a programming question, so I will close it.

FYI:

BigQuery offers a free query tier for all users (the first 100 GB of data processed per month is at no charge). If you plan on using your own data, and not just test BigQuery with our sample public datasets, then you must enable billing, as there is no free storage tier. See: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/pricing

The D0 tier of Cloud SQL is less than a dollar a day, see:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/billing

Comment: you are required to insert your credit card details in there. which is not the same thing as free. I don't want to tell google my credit card data and TRUST it not to charge me. or be panicked about oh is this query going to charge me...